# Who can be a good replacement for Trashcan Carla?

Tags: fallout-4

I killed Trashcan Carla. After three lines with her, I knew it had to be done. I'm pretty sure almost everyone has done it.

Now that I'm realizing that she had good junk, I miss her. (Should have put a ring on it.) Where do I find another provider like her?

Comment: Still trying to figure out why you would kill her. So I am willing to say most people didn't kill her. Even if she was a normal wondering npc wouldn't kill her. I recommend reloading a save so you can have advantage of the junk she sells being inside one of your settlements

Comment: She had a big mouth, so I hit her once, just as I had done with other NPCs... She started to fire at me, crazy! It all went down hill from there... A settler saw it and fired the siren... The cops arrived... Another, passing, settler that had been drinking attacked everything that moved... Havoc broke in and now she lies naked on the street. Can I move the body?

Comment: @givanse You can move the body. I'd suggest dropping it in the nearby river. But how to do that would be another question. (Probably already asked somewhere here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you construct a Trade Caravan Post in one of your settlements, you'll find that it is frequently visited by one of the several roaming vendors normally found out and about in the Commonwealth. Depending on what you're looking for in a "Trashcan Carla replacement" these may or may not fully suit your needs. But the post is handy to have regardless.

If you do not have the Trade Caravan Post available for construction already, make your way to Bunker Hill and complete a few quests there. It's probably best to stay friendly with those folks, too. I don't know the exact trigger, and the Internet seems uncertain as well, but most sources I've found indicate that one of the Bunker Hill quests (nobody else seems to know which, either) should unlock the item.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple merchants offer a large variety of junk, like Trashcan Carla. Some of them are stationary and pretty easy to find:

- Deb at Bunker Hill
- Alexis Combes in Vault 81
- Daisy in Goodneighbor
- Myrna in Diamond City
- Trudy at Drumlin Dinner
- Penny Fitzgerald in Covenant

If you were using Trashcan Carla to buy shipments, there's also some replacements:

- Daisy and Alexis Combes for Circuitry
- Penny Fitzgerald for Asbestos
- Deb and Daisy for Crystal

You can also have your own junk merchants by building a Trading Stand/Shop/Emporium in one of your settlements and assigning a settler to it.

You will however need two points in the perk Local Leader (Requires 6 charisma). Two points in Cap Collector (Charisma 1) are also required to have a level 3 Trading Post.

Comment: +1, I was going to suggest Trudy, as she is pretty close to Sanctuary and has plenty of junk. Still, it's better if Carla is alive as she is often at Trudy's, giving you two junk dealers there.

Answer (score 0):

Best junk dealers I've found are in Diamond City Market and Bunker Hill. You can also establish a general Trader store in your settlements.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the prep school mission for Kessler at Bunker Hill. She said, "Build a safe place for the caravans and we all profit." I believe after this mission you can build the caravan item. I'd suggest doing it at Sanctuary Hill if it is fortified.

Comment: Your post has useful information, but it doesn’t seem to answer the question clearly. Could you please [edit] your post to more directly address the question?